# Extract ids of child objects in has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have `User` model, which `has_many` post. I would like to query the list of ids of posts by users.
However, the following returns array of post objects instead of just `id`

```
@user.posts
```

What would be the ActiveRecord way to get just ids? I know I can use

```
@user.posts.map{|u| u.id}
```

But I think it is inefficient (returning array of post objects, then extract ID) and verbose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best would be to use:

```
@user.post_ids
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mischa. Is this method_missing implemented by ActiveRecord?

Comment: I think AR is dinamically defining methods (via `class_eval`) instead of using method_missing. See: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb#L72

Answer (score 3):

`@user.posts.pluck(:id)`

I think this should grab them.

Comment: Thanks. This is less verbose for sure. But I am afraid it will still fetch entire objects (which includes long body text), and thus not very efficient.

Comment: Adam, it wouldn't. `(0.7ms)  SELECT id FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."user_id" = 1` is what is generated

Comment: According to [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) `pluck` executes a SQL query against the column itself.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for explaining it to me, varatis.

Answer (score 1):

Rails provides a handy method for doing this:

`@user.post_ids`

should do what you want

Comment: oops, didn't mean to double post the same solution, mischa was 10 seconds faster ; )